# Windows 10 1909 BLE Connecting Without Pairing

Tags: uwp, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to design a Windows UWP app and I am trying to connect to a BLE device without the need to explicitly pair.

To verify that the problem is not on the BLE device side I confirmed that I can connect to the BLE device with the 'Just Works' option through the NRF connect app on Android, and on iOS.

Some info about my setup and things I have done so far:

I have Bluetooth capabilities enabled in the Manifest.
I have tested that bluetooth works when pairing directly with a separate device that uses BLE such as some headphones.
I have made sure that Bluetooth is turned on.
I can connect to my BLE device when I used the pairing option however it displays a popup each time and I don't want that popup, I want it to just work without any interaction.
When PairAsync is not used the result of FromBluetoothAddressAsync or FromIdAsync  is 'Disconnected'.
I am using Windows 10 1909 18363.900. I should note that this used to work on 1803.
All of my bluetooth drivers are up to date. I tried this on another laptop and it did not work without the pairing popup also.

Here is my code:

```
        private string DEVICE_ADDRESS_TEST = "C7:9C:0C:EE:EA:D1";
        // Create BLE watcher
        var bleWatcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher() { ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active };

        // add received callback
        bleWatcher.Received += async (BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher w, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs btAdv) => {
            try
            {
                /// SCAN FIND DEVICE
                ulong longAgain = ulong.Parse(this.DEVICE_ADDRESS_TEST.Replace(":", ""), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                if (btAdv.BluetoothAddress != longAgain)
                {
                    Logging.info($"Found device: {btAdv.BluetoothAddress}");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    Logging.info($"Found BLE device [{DEVICE_ADDRESS_TEST}]");
                    bleWatcher.Stop();
                }

                // This causes a popup to appear! I don't want this.
                //DevicePairingResult result = await di.Pairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingProtectionLevel.Encryption); 
                // This causes a popup to appear! I don't want this.
                //DevicePairingResult result = await di.Pairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingProtectionLevel.None); 

                /// CONNECT TO DEVICE
                Logging.info("Connecting...");
                var device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(longAgain);


                var log1 = $"Connection state: [{device.ConnectionStatus}]";
                Logging.info(log1);
                if (device.ConnectionStatus != BluetoothConnectionStatus.Connected)
                {
                    throw new Exception("FromBluetoothAddressAsync did not connect successfully.");
                }

                /// GET ALL SERVICES
                Logging.info("Getting services..");
                // 2) SERVICES!!
                var result = await device.GetGattServicesAsync();

                if (result.Status != GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"GetGattServicesAsync failed with result: status[{result.Status}], error[{result.ProtocolError}]");
                }

                Logging.info($"[{result.Services.Count}] services found");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logging.error(e.Message);
            }

        };
        bleWatcher.Start();
```

What am I doing wrong? There has to be a way to connect to devices without needing to interact with a popup. Is there a new API I am missing? Please help!

**UPDATE:**

I found that performing a GetGattServicesForUuidAsync or GetGattServicesAsync results in the device connecting however they both return the status 'Unreachable'. This is odd because I can see a light that denotes if a device is connected or not. Again I have to reiterate that this behavior is only on the window platform as I can easily connect and get services using the 'just workings' on android and ios.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the pairing SS:
[image]

Comment: *`displays a popup`* could you share the screenshot about that?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I updated the topic with the SS, please see above. Again just to be clear I want to avoid pairing if possible.

Comment: I tried above code but I can't reproduce your issue, could you share your more detail about the app's target and min version, and I notice that it works without popup in 1803.

Comment: Target is 1903 build 18362, Min version is fall creators update build 16299

Comment: It should be noted that the "Bluetooth LE Explorer" offered by Microsoft on the store scans correctly but does not connect also. I have tested this on two separate PC's with bluetooth functionality.

Comment: Ok, Please share your Bluetooth device information.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this in a while but for BLE you need to create a Pairing Event handler. you can actually bypass, or at least you could, that popup by sending 0 as pairing code for BLE.
Something like:

```
private async void BLEBeaconReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
 {
  var dv = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(args.BluetoothAddress);
  if (!dv.DeviceInformation.Pairing.IsPaired)
     {
      dv.DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom.PairingRequested += HandlerPairingReq;
      var prslt = await  
      v.DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom.PairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly, DevicePairingProtectionLevel.None);
       ..
       ..
      }
  }
```

HandlerPairingReq code:

```
        private void HandlerPairingReq(DeviceInformationCustomPairing CP, DevicePairingRequestedEventArgs DPR)
        {
            var deff = DPR.GetDeferral();
            DPR.Accept("0");
            Log.It("Custom Pairing - 0 sent." + DPR.DeviceInformation, op);            
            deff.Complete();
            CP.PairingRequested -= HandlerPairingReq;
        }
```

Once Windows knows the device and is paired it wont need to be paired again. Even for BLE. I was hoping with later versions of BLE from MS that the need to pair would be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It is unconfirmed because we ended up scrapping the windows BLE application due to BLE not working but I believe there was an issue with the bluetooth firmware and I recently saw there had been a BLE update from windows that may have fixed the issue. Unconfirmed but closing this out.

Cheers!